# Ionic Lab, 404 Not Found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I try to run "ionic lab", nothing bad happened in the terminal:

> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
>
> ionic-lab http://localhost:8100 --host localhost --port 8200 --app-name ion-Dev --app-version 0.0.1

```
[INFO] Development server running!

   Lab: http://localhost:8200
   Local: http://localhost:8100
   External: http://192.168.0.108:8100
   DevApp: ion-Healthbook@8100 on MacBook-Air-de-Jonathan.local

   Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8200!

[ng] Date: 2018-08-11T19:17:47.922Z
[ng] Hash: 2107c976feaae9ab2daf
[ng] Time: 33926ms
[ng] chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 21.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {create-checklist-checklist-module} create-checklist-checklist-module.js, create-checklist-checklist-module.js.map (create-checklist-checklist-module) 21.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {create-doctor-doctor-module} create-doctor-doctor-module.js, create-doctor-doctor-module.js.map (create-doctor-doctor-module) 37.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {create-patient-patient-module} create-patient-patient-module.js, create-patient-patient-module.js.map (create-patient-patient-module) 37.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {edit-doctor-doctor-module} edit-doctor-doctor-module.js, edit-doctor-doctor-module.js.map (edit-doctor-doctor-module) 40.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {edit-patient-patient-module} edit-patient-patient-module.js, edit-patient-patient-module.js.map (edit-patient-patient-module) 39.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {listview-checklist-checklist-module} listview-checklist-checklist-module.js, listview-checklist-checklist-module.js.map (listview-checklist-checklist-module) 24.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {listview-listview-module} listview-listview-module.js, listview-listview-module.js.map (listview-listview-module) 75.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {login-login-module} login-login-module.js, login-login-module.js.map (login-login-module) 10.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 54.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 226 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-checklist-checklist-module} profile-checklist-checklist-module.js, profile-checklist-checklist-module.js.map (profile-checklist-checklist-module) 24.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-doctor-send-send-module} profile-doctor-send-send-module.js, profile-doctor-send-send-module.js.map (profile-doctor-send-send-module) 20.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-profile-module} profile-profile-module.js, profile-profile-module.js.map (profile-profile-module) 276 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-proxy-edit-edit-module} profile-proxy-edit-edit-module.js, profile-proxy-edit-edit-module.js.map (profile-proxy-edit-edit-module)28.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-proxy-new-new-module} profile-proxy-new-new-module.js, profile-proxy-new-new-module.js.map (profile-proxy-new-new-module) 26.6 kB [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-proxy-send-send-module} profile-proxy-send-send-module.js, profile-proxy-send-send-module.js.map (profile-proxy-send-send-module)20.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-send-send-module} profile-send-send-module.js, profile-send-send-module.js.map (profile-send-send-module) 19.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {profile-send-template-template-module} profile-send-template-template-module.js, profile-send-template-template-module.js.map (profile-send-template-template-module) 13.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {129} 129.js, 129.js.map () 19.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 8.98 kB [entry] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 68.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.44 MB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {0} 0.js, 0.js.map () 45.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {1} 1.js, 1.js.map () 43.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {2} 2.js, 2.js.map () 45.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {3} 3.js, 3.js.map () 43.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {4} 4.js, 4.js.map () 2.43 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {5} 5.js, 5.js.map () 2.31 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {6} 6.js, 6.js.map () 207 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {7} 7.js, 7.js.map () 201 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {8} 8.js, 8.js.map () 209 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {9} 9.js, 9.js.map () 203 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {10} 10.js, 10.js.map () 13.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {11} 11.js, 11.js.map () 21.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {12} 12.js, 12.js.map () 21.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {13} 13.js, 13.js.map () 9.13 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {14} 14.js, 14.js.map () 9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {15} 15.js, 15.js.map () 9.12 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {16} 16.js, 16.js.map () 9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {17} 17.js, 17.js.map () 11.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {18} 18.js, 18.js.map () 10.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {19} 19.js, 19.js.map () 11.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {20} 20.js, 20.js.map () 10.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {21} 21.js, 21.js.map () 6.71 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {22} 22.js, 22.js.map () 6.63 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {23} 23.js, 23.js.map () 6.71 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {24} 24.js, 24.js.map () 6.63 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {25} 25.js, 25.js.map () 23.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {26} 26.js, 26.js.map () 22.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {27} 27.js, 27.js.map () 23.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {28} 28.js, 28.js.map () 22.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {29} 29.js, 29.js.map () 9.62 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {30} 30.js, 30.js.map () 9.51 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {31} 31.js, 31.js.map () 9.33 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {32} 32.js, 32.js.map () 9.24 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {33} 33.js, 33.js.map () 14.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {34} 34.js, 34.js.map () 14.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {35} 35.js, 35.js.map () 14.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {36} 36.js, 36.js.map () 14.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {37} 37.js, 37.js.map () 9.76 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {38} 38.js, 38.js.map () 9.65 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {39} 39.js, 39.js.map () 7.21 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {40} 40.js, 40.js.map () 7.05 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {41} 41.js, 41.js.map () 19.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {42} 42.js, 42.js.map () 19.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {43} 43.js, 43.js.map () 19.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {44} 44.js, 44.js.map () 19 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {45} 45.js, 45.js.map () 36.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {46} 46.js, 46.js.map () 36.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {47} 47.js, 47.js.map () 17.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {48} 48.js, 48.js.map () 16.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {49} 49.js, 49.js.map () 17 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {50} 50.js, 50.js.map () 16.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {51} 51.js, 51.js.map () 5.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {52} 52.js, 52.js.map () 2.44 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {53} 53.js, 53.js.map () 2.41 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {54} 54.js, 54.js.map () 13.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {55} 55.js, 55.js.map () 13.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {56} 56.js, 56.js.map () 18.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {57} 57.js, 57.js.map () 18 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {58} 58.js, 58.js.map () 18.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {59} 59.js, 59.js.map () 18 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {60} 60.js, 60.js.map () 24.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {61} 61.js, 61.js.map () 23.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {62} 62.js, 62.js.map () 24.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {63} 63.js, 63.js.map () 23.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {64} 64.js, 64.js.map () 14.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {65} 65.js, 65.js.map () 14.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {66} 66.js, 66.js.map () 16.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {67} 67.js, 67.js.map () 16 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {68} 68.js, 68.js.map () 21.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {69} 69.js, 69.js.map () 21.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {70} 70.js, 70.js.map () 21.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {71} 71.js, 71.js.map () 21.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {72} 72.js, 72.js.map () 16.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {73} 73.js, 73.js.map () 16.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {74} 74.js, 74.js.map () 2.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {75} 75.js, 75.js.map () 19.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {76} 76.js, 76.js.map () 19.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {77} 77.js, 77.js.map () 2.93 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {78} 78.js, 78.js.map () 2.95 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {79} 79.js, 79.js.map () 15.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {80} 80.js, 80.js.map () 15.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {81} 81.js, 81.js.map () 14 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {82} 82.js, 82.js.map () 7.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {83} 83.js, 83.js.map () 7.25 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {84} 84.js, 84.js.map () 17.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {85} 85.js, 85.js.map () 21.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {86} 86.js, 86.js.map () 19.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {87} 87.js, 87.js.map () 19.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {88} 88.js, 88.js.map () 19 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {89} 89.js, 89.js.map () 13.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {90} 90.js, 90.js.map () 13 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {91} 91.js, 91.js.map () 12.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {92} 92.js, 92.js.map () 12.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {93} 93.js, 93.js.map () 9.05 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {94} 94.js, 94.js.map () 1.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {95} 95.js, 95.js.map () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {96} 96.js, 96.js.map () 11.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {97} 97.js, 97.js.map () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {98} 98.js, 98.js.map () 11.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {99} 99.js, 99.js.map () 9.68 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {100} 100.js, 100.js.map () 9.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {101} 101.js, 101.js.map () 32.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {102} 102.js, 102.js.map () 30.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {103} 103.js, 103.js.map () 33.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {104} 104.js, 104.js.map () 31.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {105} 105.js, 105.js.map () 6.61 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {106} 106.js, 106.js.map () 6.59 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {107} 107.js, 107.js.map () 10.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {108} 108.js, 108.js.map () 10.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {109} 109.js, 109.js.map () 10.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {110} 110.js, 110.js.map () 10.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {111} 111.js, 111.js.map () 16.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {112} 112.js, 112.js.map () 16.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {113} 113.js, 113.js.map () 20.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {114} 114.js, 114.js.map () 19.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {115} 115.js, 115.js.map () 19.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {116} 116.js, 116.js.map () 18.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {117} 117.js, 117.js.map () 9.46 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {118} 118.js, 118.js.map () 14.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {119} 119.js, 119.js.map () 1.28 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {120} 120.js, 120.js.map () 2.36 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {121} 121.js, 121.js.map () 1.39 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {122} 122.js, 122.js.map () 8.11 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {123} 123.js, 123.js.map () 9.87 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {124} 124.js, 124.js.map () 4.64 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {125} 125.js, 125.js.map () 1.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {126} 126.js, 126.js.map () 3.94 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {127} 127.js, 127.js.map () 6.35 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {128} 128.js, 128.js.map () 10.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

But in the browser I don't see anything, in the console shows this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8200/build/ionlab/ionlab.z0nyl9ye.js
```

package = "@ionic/lab": "^1.0.6"

If I use "ionic serve" everything works fine.

Maybe If I could change the port of ionic lab.

I'm using Ionic Lab on Ionic 4.0.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to solve the problem go to the folder
`Path_to_your_project\node_modules\@ionic\lab\www\build\ionlab`
and rename the file `ionlab.925lkwi9.js` to `ionlab.z0nyl9ye.js`.
Now it should work.